# How can I parse this XML with XmlSerializer attributes?

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

We need to use a "web service" which communicates extremely ugly XML. It is not developed by us and there is zero chance to make its developers understand proper XML.

*FYI, this web service also accepts the same kind of XML in a HTTP GET URL parameter (not the request body) - and the guys who developed it don't understand why that is a bad practice.*

So, what is the fastest way to map an XML such as this:

```
<foo id="document">
    <foo id="customer">
        <bar name="firstname" value="Joe"/>
        <bar name="lastname" value="Smith"/>
        <foo id="address">
            <bar name="city" value="New York"/>
            <bar name="country" value="USA"/>
        </foo>
    </foo>
    <bar name="somemoredata1" value="123"/>
    <bar name="somemoredata2" value="abc"/>
</foo>
```

into classes like this:

```
public class Document
{
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }

    public int SomeMoreData1 { get; set; }

    public string SomeMoreData2 { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public Address Address { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
}


public class Address
{
    public string City { get; set; }

    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

using eg. XML Serializer attributes or any other way that needs as little boilerplate code as possible.

I made up the `foo` and `bar` element names, but the structure of the XML I need to parse is based on the exact same convention.

I could of course implement `IXmlSerializable` manually in these classes or just make `Foo` and `Bar` classes and use those with the `XmlSerializer`, but none of these options seem to be a good solution.

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: Do you need to do it with XmlSerialiser? I often find it easier just to parse-and-build with XmlReader even with good XML, never mind crazy XML.

Comment: It would be simplest to parse it with XmlSerializer, yes. If you have a better or easier solution, write an answer! :) I'm curious about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with XML serializer attributes: there is just no way to make it take a field name out of a specified attribute. You will have to deserialize manually (possibly generating the boilerplate) or pre-process the XML — a simple XSLT along the following lines will do the trick:

```
<xsl:template match="foo">
  <xsl:element name="{@id}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="bar">
  <xsl:element name="{@name}">
    <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

**Update:** for the reverse transformation:

```
<xsl:template match="*[count(child::text())=1]">
  <bar value="{text()}" name="{local-name()}"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
  <foo id="{local-name()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </foo>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hah, your XSLT idea is so far the most elegant! One more thing about it: how can I transform the XML outputted by the serializer back to the ugly format? I'm asking because I'm kinda unfamiliar with XSLT.

Comment: Added xslt for the reverse transformation and fixed the other one.

Comment: Thank you Anton! XSLT saves the day. :)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used the xml serializer or deserializer myself, but I do use LINQ to parse out my XML doc into objects. If your classes are fairly simply, you may look into that route.

Comment: +1 for recommending LINQ to XML; however, if the XML pasted above is representative of the XML OP is receiving, it might prove challenging because it does not look well-formed (no root node for example).

Comment: The reason I'm thinking about XmlSerializer is that it saves me from the need to write lots of boilerplate code.

Answer (score 1):

Since you say in a comment that you are plumping for for XmlSerializer for simplicity rather than because that approach is enforced by other concerns, here's a different approach. Since it seems that the names of the elements is insignificant in the document, I ignore it in the parsing, though one can test that too. With more pleasant XML formats, that would be the main thing that the parsing would key off (generally with with a `switch` on the element names):

```
private static Document ParseDocument(XmlReader xr)
{
    Document doc = new Document();
    while(xr.Read())
      if(xr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
        if(xr.GetAttribute("id") == "customer")
          doc.Customer = ParseCustomer(xr.ReadSubtree());
        else
          switch(xr.GetAttribute("name"))
          {
            case "somemoredata1":
              doc.SomeMoreData1 = int.Parse(xr.GetAttribute("value"));
              break;
            case "somemoredata2":
              doc.SomeMoreData2 = xr.GetAttribute("value");
              break;
          }
      //Put some validation of doc here if necessary.
      return doc;
}
private static Customer ParseCustomer(XmlReader xr)
{
  Customer cu = new Customer();
  while(xr.Read())
    if(xr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
      if(xr.GetAttribute("id") == "address")
        cu.Address = ParseAddress(xr.ReadSubtree());
      else
        switch(xr.GetAttribute("name"))
        {
          case "firstname":
            cu.FirstName = xr.GetAttribute("value");
            break;
          case "lastname":
            cu.LastName = xr.GetAttribute("value");
            break;
        }
    //validate here if necessary.
    return cu;
}
private static Address ParseAddress(XmlReader xr)
{
  Address add = new Address();
  while(xr.Read())
    if(xr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
      switch(xr.GetAttribute("name"))
      {
        case "city":
          add.City = xr.GetAttribute("value");
          break;
        case "country":
          add.Country = xr.GetAttribute("value");
          break;
      }
  return add;
}
```

It's not exactly pretty (it's not terribly pretty with nice XML to work off, but it tends not to be quite as bad), but it works, and the use of subtrees can be nice with some complicated structures where the same type can turn up in different places within the document. One can replace the static methods that set values from the outside with contstructors that take the `XmlReader` which allows one to ensure class invariants, and/or have the objects immutable.

This approach comes into its own in the case of large documents that you want to deserialise as a large series of the same sort of items (or a large series of just a few types), because one can `yield` them out as they're created, which can make quite a difference to the delay to first response.

Comment: Jon. I almost downvoted your  use of `using` in this case. The `XmlReader` was passed in to the method, and the caller may still need it.

Comment: @JohnSaunders to do what? The doc in the OP would be read to the end when finished, so the only thing left to do with the `XmlReader` is dispose it. If they were going to want to "rewind" then they'd need to have it stored in some way (string, XmlDocument, etc) that they could still re-use either way, and the the XmlReader came from a `ReadSubtree()` then the call to `Dispose()` would not prevent further reading of the "parent" reader. Granted, I would likely have the `using` higher up the stack, but it should be in the complete use somewhere, so I put it in to represent good practice.

Comment: Disposing a resource passed in to a method is _not_ a best practice.

Comment: Jon, this kind of code is a pain to write and maintain. This is exactly why I'd prefer the serializer.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Really, you wouldn't dispose an `IDataReader` created with `CommandBehavior.CloseConnection` and passed to an iterator method in the iterator method?

Comment: I would dispose it in the caller, to keep it clean. I don't like implicitly delegating responsibility for the disposal. if there were some clearly-legible pattern for this, then sure. My problem is that you can't look at the call and know that the method being called is being passed responsibility for the `IDisposable`.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Yeah, If I'd the calling method in the demo code, I'd have it there, but I don't, so I don't. There are certainly cases where passing ownership is the way to go in real code though. Dispose the `IDataReader` in the hypothetical case in the comment above, and the use of the results will throw an exception.

Comment: Venemo, if this were a full example, I'd agree with him too. Examples often take liberties and I took the liberty of putting the using there rather than the liberty of not having one. As for maintainability, with nicer formats this approach tends to be better than it is here, though still not as nice as XmlSerialiser. I would recommend it when either the ability to get member objects quickly is important or where the format is making XmlSerialiser more troublesome than it normally is. This being an example of the latter.

Comment: Jon, the problem with examples using different standards of quality than the "real code" is that readers will copy and paste examples, thinking it is "real code". Throw in a truncated example of the call, move the `using`, and I'll stop complaining. Recall that I didn't downvote.

Comment: @JohnSaunders And on consideration, the example above is relatively full, which makes variations from what one would want in the real thing more serious. Editted accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

You can try the "XML Schema Definition-Tool" ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx )

Ciao!
  Stefan